# CSS hover, transition effect in the same direction

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

I am doing some basic CSS fill transitions on hover. I have used this codepen as an example: https://codepen.io/brandon4117/pen/ihIgE. Now on hover the background position raises to fill the div, and on hover off, the background goes back down. I wanted to know how can I modify this pen, to work such as when hover off the transition should go upwards, rather than down.

Most hover transitions: Hover on new fill top->bottom. Hover off new fill removes bottom->top. I would like to do on hover fill top->bottom, on hover off fill removes top->bottom again.

A look at the CSS being used:

```
div {border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
color: black;
padding: 50px;
background-size: 200% 200%;
background-image: 
linear-gradient(to top, #A72424 50%, transparent 50%);
background-position:0 100%;
-webkit-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
-moz-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
-ms-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
-o-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;

}

div:hover {color: white;
border-color: #A72424;
background-image: 
linear-gradient(to top, #A72424 50%, transparent 50%);
background-position: 0 0%;
-webkit-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
-moz-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
-ms-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
-o-transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
transition: background-position 300ms, color 300ms ease, border-color 300ms ease;
}

a {color: black; text-decoration: none;
transition: all 100ms linear;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 100ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 100ms linear;
-o-transition: all 100ms linear;}

a:hover {color: white;
transition: all 100ms linear;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 100ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 100ms linear;
-o-transition: all 100ms linear;
}

a:active {color: white;}
```

Thanks

Comment: Play with `linear-gradient` first of all...You should try something yourself first - this is how SO works. You show what you did, and people help you improve your work. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your response, my question is that there are two states: 1) On hover where I have some background-position and the original background-position which is what our control will default to on hover off. How can I get the transition in the same direction as the fill on hover?

Comment: `transition` doesn't have a _reverse_ value, like `animation` has, so to accomplish such transition effect you either need to combine it with a script, or use `animation`

Comment: There might be some options using a couple of extra child elements, or the pseudo elements.

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp They have some pretty cool stuff, which is very easy to implement. It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but still...

Answer (score -1):

Ok I got the answer: For top down do this:

```
.divclass::after {
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.3s;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    width: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 120%;
}



.divclass:hover::after {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Thanks for pointing me in the direction of pseudos Frderico

Comment: Provide a proper code sample both at the question and the answer, that explains and shows, with a working code snippet, it all works, as with the existing, it is difficult to see how it can.